# Can a person benefit from damaging terrorists?

Tags: united-states, refugee-law

A few months ago Islamic Revolutionary Guard Corps (Sepaah Pasdaran) of Iran was designated as a terrorist organization by USA. As a person who lives in Iran I was wondering if I damage Islamic Revolutionary Guard Corps in anyway, say damaging their personnel or their properties, can I be protected by USA? For example can I come to USA as a refugee.

Comment: I think this would be a question for the consulate, but I'm pretty sure that the answer is "no", personal fighting against the IRGC isn't an "in" to refugee immigration, probably quite the opposite.

Comment: The Kurdish translators embedded with the US Forces in Iraq weren't given any refugee clearance to come to the US. Don't stick your head out.

Comment: https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/only-2-iraqi-translators-who-worked-u-s-troops-got-n1035661

Answer (score 1):

The basic requirement for being granted refugee status is demonstrating that you have been persecuted or have a well-founded fear that you will be persecuted, and is connected to race, religion, nationality, social group membership or political opinion (there are other grounds such as reunification with close family in the US). What you describe doesn't clearly fill the bill (was this just youthful vandalism?). A pattern of public politically dangerous statements would probably be necessary – there isn't a clear objective legal statement of what constitutes evidence that you have a reasonable fear of persecution.
A prerequisite is a referral from the [U.S. Refugee Admissions Program](https://www.state.gov/refugee-admissions/). The usual first step is apply at the US embassy, but that may be a bit difficult (but you might exit to another country).